# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: magento-1.9

In my website back end suddenly throw SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away this error how to i fix.

```
#0 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_fl...', Array)
#4 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_fl...', Array)
#5 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage_Flag), 'synchronize', 'flag_code')
#8 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Flag.php(119): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('synchronize', 'flag_code')
#9 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Flag->loadSelf()
#10 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Observer.php(47): Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage->getSyncFlag()
#11 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Core_Model_Observer->addSynchronizeNotification(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Observer), 'addSynchronizeN...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(529): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#17 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#18 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/fitfusjv/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

How to  i fix it???

Comment: Restart your mysql server.

Comment: how to restart can you please tell me

Comment: You need root access of your server. login with ssh and run command 
"service mysql restart" or you can search in google how to restart mysql server.

Comment: ok i will try..