# Magento migration 1.x admin panel error

Tags: error, admin-panel, migration

I have migrated my Magento 1.x code to new hosting provider, my website comes back good but admin fails with below admin panel error any help

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Observer.php(47): Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage->getSyncFlag() #1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart your database server or check it's permission.

reference: [SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83608/sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: I have restarted the db but still seeing the issue when hitting admin url - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function loadSelf() on boolean in /home/y3p2wg/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage.php:83 Stack trace: #0 /home/y3p2wg/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Observer.php(47): Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage->getSyncFlag() #1 /home/y3p2wg/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Mage_Core_Model_Observer->addSynchronizeNotification(Object(Varien_Event_Observer)) #2 /home/y3p2wg/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318